# Next Auth with Spring Boot Security + Jwt

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, next-auth

Thanks to all of you. I found a lot of information about everything I needed so far.
This is my first post (that means I'm desperate! Sorry for the wrong format).
We (my friend and me) are trying to build a web application using Next Auth and Spring Boot (and MongoDb).

Our backend works, we have the token generated and sent to the frontend via REST Controller.

- is this good practice? is there another / better way to send the informations?

We have the frontend working (more or less with Google) but we are bashing our heads when using credentials. After loggin in from the console i see the info from the backend:

in [...nextauth].ts

`userResponse:  { email: 'admin', accessToken: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY4ODYzMzUzOSwiZXhwIjoxNjg4NjM3MTM5fQ.VptnKvdpA8PIoBgtRAN8DuXp2-s_O7HRfk0K9J1Ct_o'         }`

but when monitoring the session, we have all the info but the token:

`token:  { email: 'admin', iat: 1688633544, exp: 1691225544, jti: '849e13e4-78db-4688-a737-507e0282b490' }`

How can we extract the info from the userResponse and use it?
Right now we are switching to a simple Login form and passing the username / password to the backend:

- if I have to encrypt the password before sending to the backend, how can I use bcrypt in the frontend and decrypt it in the backend?

Again, thanks guys!

We tried to overwrite the token but from Chrome net analyzer there's no trace of it:

in [...nextauth].ts

`session.user.accessToken = beToken;` (beToken is the backend token)

`beToken = eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY4ODYzNjQ1OCwiZXhwIjoxNjg4NjQwMDU4fQ.sWGEVJ3J7h72kguNc6fcBVEqWFz3sfhHuaawtMF_AQU`

`next-auth.csrf-token= c15b2b928cc6fa80b72006bbf3265a06b631aa311e11bfd37a726bcb32fdc5de%7C7cd0abdf1928912625d4575ea13bc8f7bd11c7c432563d15bac11b916d704807;`

`next-auth.session-token= eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0..67MdRbQE-Ijz07kT.VPfO8BRrEL75pzYh35ktrSmBjVCGMbXzfmyS1GArKfB0HDOEYFKOYK1fnqD5OmSvHu7meNjxcnwrBBsKMq5Ht0ZP95cLuO1gQXRAKur8i2cc3lLfCGF4jdBshRvCSJZ0.76CZsEA2AgkbOZAxF5pUjQ`

EDIT:
We deployed the app on Vercel, so since we have https we discarded the next-auth.
therefore the post can be closes.